# The ++ sign applications in defining array gates

Tags: omnet++

What does the ++ sign on the bottom line mean? What are its applications?
How to interpret it?

> tic[0].out++ --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> tic[1].in++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual is here to help you: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:gates

In short, it stands for the next unassigned gate in a gate vector.